# Equivalent to unix "less" command within R console

Tags: r, shell

Is there an equivalent to the unix `less` command that can be used within the R console?

Comment: Are you trying to look at things in the file system, or within the R environment (I presume the latter)?

Comment: Within the R environment.  For example, if I `print` a moderately sized dataframe I want to be able to scroll through it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is also `page()` which displays a representation of an object in a pager, like less.

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10))
page(dat, method = "print")
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: When I run `page(data, method="print")` in RStudio in Windows 8, I get a prompt "How do you want to open this type of file?" with only option "Look for an app in the Store". Do others see this, how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 12):

Not really. There are the commands

- `head()` and `tail()` for showing the beginning and end of objects
- `print()` for explicitly showing an object, and just its name followed by return does the same
- `summary()` for concise summary that depends on the object
- `str()` for its structure

and more.   An equivalent for `less` would be a little orthogonal to the language and system.  Where the Unix shell offers you `less` to view the content of a file (which is presumed to be ascii-encoded), it cannot know about all types.

R is different in that it knows about the object types which is why `summary()` -- as well as the whole modeling framework -- are more appropriate.

*Follow-up edit:*  Another possibility is provided by `edit()` as well as `edit.data.frame()`.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.  I would disagree that "less" would be inappropriate - the main function for which I use less is to scroll string buffers in a console.  The R console outputs lots of string buffers.  I thought perhaps there might be a use here for buffer scrolling functionality.

Comment: You can always use `system("less")`... of course, if you use any of *NIX systems...

Comment: fmark:  another possibility is provided by `edit()` and `edit.data.frame()` which you could try.

Comment: aL3xa: Yes, but not for R objects.

Comment: @Dirk edit(), while not ideal, does what I need.  Thanks.  If you write that out as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Dirk, yup... that's the catch... =)

Answer (score 7):

I save the print output to a file and then read it using an editor or `less`.

Type the following in R

```
sink("Routput.txt")
print(varname)
sink()
```

Then in a shell:

```
less Routput.txt
```

Comment: Works well when you want to scroll through the str() of a large data set (page() does not work for this)

Comment: If you use sink("Routput.txt", split=TRUE) you can view the output in another terminal window (at least on unix) and still operate the R console. If the file gets too big, you can truncate it with ">Routput.txt" and R will keep writing to it.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is already on disk, then you can use `file.show`

Answer (score 1):

You might like my little toy here:

```
short <- function(x=seq(1,20),numel=4,skipel=0,ynam=deparse(substitute(x))) {
ynam<-as.character(ynam)
#clean up spaces
ynam<-gsub(" ","",ynam)
#unlist goes by columns, so transpose to get what's expected
if(is.list(x)) x<-unlist(t(x))
if(2*numel >= length(x)) {
    print(x)
    }
    else {  
        frist=1+skipel
        last=numel+skipel
        cat(paste(ynam,'[',frist,'] thru ',ynam,'[',last,']\n',sep=""))
        print(x[frist:last])
        cat(' ... \n')
        cat(paste(ynam,'[',length(x)-numel-skipel+1,'] thru ', ynam, '[', length(x)-skipel,']\n',sep=""))
        print(x[(length(x)-numel-skipel+1):(length(x)-skipel)])
        }
}
```

blahblah copyright by me, not Disney blahblah free for use, reuse, editing, sprinkling on your Wheaties, etc.