# Is there an R command similar to unix commands more and less?

Tags: r

In a Unix terminal, it is possible to look at a text file page by page using commands "less" or "more". I have a character vector with 300 lines and I would like to look at it page by page. Do you know a similar function in R ?

Comment: `head(dat)` or `tail(dat)` ?

Comment: Yes but then only show the first and the last lines.

Comment: Try some of the solutions on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837520/how-to-prevent-the-output-of-r-to-scroll-away-in-bash

`page(dat, method="print")` looks promising

Comment: [Equivalent to unix “less” command within R console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842579/equivalent-to-unix-less-command-within-r-console)

Comment: I would like to have a look at the character vector in the console, not in a new page like with the page() function.

Comment: You can still use your system command , using `system` or `shell`,for example `system('less dat.txt',intern=TRUE)`

Comment: If you are just interested in the first/last line of a vector, wouldn't then dat[1] and dat[length(dat)] work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to an object in your `R` environment (as opposed to a file on your drive),

You might like my little toy here:

```
short <- function(x=seq(1,20),numel=4,skipel=0,ynam=deparse(substitute(x))) {
ynam<-as.character(ynam)
#clean up spaces
ynam<-gsub(" ","",ynam)
#unlist goes by columns, so transpose to get what's expected
if(is.list(x)) x<-unlist(t(x))
if(2*numel >= length(x)) {
    print(x)
    }
    else {  
        frist=1+skipel
        last=numel+skipel
        cat(paste(ynam,'[',frist,'] thru ',ynam,'[',last,']\n',sep=""))
        print(x[frist:last])
        cat(' ... \n')
        cat(paste(ynam,'[',length(x)-numel-skipel+1,'] thru ', ynam, '[', length(x)-skipel,']\n',sep=""))
        print(x[(length(x)-numel-skipel+1):(length(x)-skipel)])
        }
}
```

blahblah copyright by me, not Disney blahblah free for use, reuse, editing, sprinkling on your Wheaties, etc.

Comment: How does this work. It seems similar to head(). Am I wrong ?

Comment: @PAC yes it's similar, but `numel` specifies how many elements to return, `skipel` lets you start anywhere (not just at the top), and it returns `numel` elements from both the beginning and the end of the data.  You can easily mod the code if you want only "head" xor "tail" returned.