# R console output too long, how can I view outputs in `less`?

Tags: r

I am inspecting research data from NIR spectroscopy. Unfortunately, the output is too big (2048 rows with 15 columns).

Very often, when I try to check a variable like `mymodel$loadings` my results get truncated.

I understand that I can increase the max output of my terminal, but it's really a hassle to scroll my mouse up from my terminal window. Is there a way I can tell R to pipe the output from my last statement to `less` or `more` so I can just scroll using the keyboard?

Comment: You could use `head()` and `tail()` to see the first and lasts observations. If you try to print a sufficiently long object, you will get a message:  `[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 900001 entries ]`. You could also subset (`g[100:105]`).

Comment: Why do you want to look at 2048 rows and 15 columns? Look at data summaries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent to unix "less" command within R console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842579/equivalent-to-unix-less-command-within-r-console)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a version of [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/)?  I would generally look at tables like this in the Data Viewer pane, it allows you to see all data in tables like yours a lot easier.

Access by clicking on the data frame name in top right, or using below in console:

```
View(dataframe_name)
```